# Saving user uploaded image to folder and/or server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I have an app, that allows users to upload an image, crop it and with other data save it all as html file to be used as a footer for emails. The image is given to them as base64.

Howver turns out this is not supported by Outlook, since it doesnt accept b64 data as img source.

So my idea was to save the cropped image to a file, let's say /public/avatars/avatar.png and link it's directory as a source. However I'm having trouble finding a way how to save images to to a file using JS. My allowed stack is JS and React, no node.js.

How would I do that? I can have the file as either b64 ot canvas element, so i'm flexible here, as long as it's saved to file.

I'm open to other solutions too.

Comment: So what are you using for a server?

Comment: App is hosted somewhere, I only have access to it's FTP though. Is that enough?

Comment: I don't think so, you would have to put any credentials into the client so they could upload their own picture, which if your setup is what I'm thinking would let them hack your site.  I think your best bet would be to use something like [firebase cloud storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) or [Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can't save a file with client language only. You have to save it to a server, own server or external server or a service like AWS.

The best solution without server-side (strangly) is to use a API for save image and get link from this API. Then you can use this link to Outlook.

You can use https://aws.amazon.com/fr/cloudfront/ free for one year with 50Go and 2 millon request monthly.

If you do not exceed 300,000 images per year you can use this service : https://cloudinary.com/pricing

You can also use https://www.deviantart.com/developers/ but that's not really the point of service.

### Weird solution :

Be careful, the login and password of your FTP user will be available in the source of your code. Minimum rights must be administered.

You can use this script for talk to FTP server from JS (not tested but seems worked) : http://www.petertorpey.com/files/ae/scripts/FTPConnection.jsx

You can try something like that :

```
var ftp = new FtpConnection("ftp://URL") ;
ftp.login("username", "password");

ftp.cd("FOLDER") // For move to folder
ftp.put(file,"FILE.PNG") ; // File must be a File JS Object

ftp.close() ;
```

Comment: Is not, you need to use server code like C#, node or PHP for write on FTP. It's too dangerous to talk with the FTP server from the JS. Anyone could then do what they want on the server